# nginx - read custom header from upstream server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy and trying to read a custom header from the response of an upstream server (Apache) without success. The Apache response is the following:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 20:18:29 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
My-custom-header: 1
```

I want to read the value from **My-custom-header** and use it in a if clause:

```
location / {
    // ...
    // get My-custom-header value here
    // ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's not only possible, it's easy:

in nginx the response header values are available through a variable (one per header).
See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24sent_http_HEADER for the details on those variables.

In your examle the variable would be $sent_http_My_custom_header.

Comment: As it turns out, this isn't correct either. OP asked to read the value for a response header. You should use `$sent_http_my_custom_header`. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_sent_http_

Comment: check @dev-gosain answer below if you need upstream response header

Comment: the answer is wrong. The person asking is trying to access the header from **upstream** server. Correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/30879181/111995

Comment: This answer was made *more* wrong by an edit in 2015, where `$sent_http_` was replaced by `$http_`. I've reverted that edit now. The answer is still incorrect. `$sent_http_name` is a **client** response header, sent from NGINX to the client. The OP is asking for **upstream** response headers, the entries in the response from the upstream server back to NGINX. The difference between the two matters as some headers are not forwarded from upstream to client. Also, you **can't use response header variables in an `if` condition**.

Comment: please update the link. It doesn't work

Comment: For me it works to use `$upstream_http_custom_header`

Answer (score 76):

When using NGINX as a proxy, there are **four** sets of headers:

- `client -> nginx`: the client *request* headers
- `nginx -> upstream`: the upstream *request* headers
- `upstream -> nginx`: the upstream *response* headers
- `nginx -> client`: the client *response* headers

You appear to be asking about the upstream response headers. Those are found in the [`$upstream_http_name` variables](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_http_).

**However**, take into account that any *response* headers are only set *after* the headers from the upstream server response have been received. Any [`if` directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) are run *before sending the upstream request*, and will not have access to any response headers! In other words, `if` directives are run after the client request has been received, before making the upstream request.

If you need to change how a response is handled, you can use a [`map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) however to set variables based on response headers, then use those variables in [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) (set client response headers), [`log_format`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) or any othere directives that are active during the response phases (internally named the [`NGX_HTTP_CONTENT_PHASE` and `NGX_HTTP_LOG_PHASE` phases](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases)). For more complex control you'll have to use a scripting add-on such as the [Lua module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) (e.g. using a [`header_filter_by_lua_block` directive](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#header_filter_by_lua_block)).

To read or set individual headers, use:

| from | to | type | read (variable) | write (directive) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client | nginx | request | [`$http_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) | – |
| ngnix | upstream | request | – | [`proxy_set_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) |
| upstream | nginx | response | [`$upstream_http_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_http_) | – |
| nginx | client | response | [`$sent_http_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_sent_http_) | [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) |

NGINX copies certain headers from client request to upstream request, and from upstream response to client response using various [`proxy_` directives](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html), giving you options to omit or explicitly include headers for either direction. So if an upstream response header is only found in `$upstream_http_name` variables, then those headers were specifically not copied to the client response, and the set of available `$sent_http_name` variables will include any *extra* headers set by NGINX that are not present in the upstream response.

Answer (score 63):

I was facing the same issue. I tried both `$http_my_custom_header` and `$sent_http_my_custom_header` but it did not work for me.

Although solved this issue by using `$upstream_http_my_custom_header`.

Comment: The appropriate variable `$upstream_http_name` pattern is documented here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables

Answer (score 12):

Use $http_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER

You can write some-thing like

```
set my_header $http_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER;
if($my_header != 'some-value') {
#do some thing;
}
```

Comment: man says - the last part of a variable name is the field name converted to __lower case__ with dashes replaced by underscores.