# nginx reject request if header not present

Tags: nginx

I need nginx to reject requests if header `StaticCookie` is not present. I don't care about its value, I just need for it to exist.

What I came up with is this, but this doesn't work. Nginx allows requests with no headers at all.

```
    if ($http_StaticCookie = false) {
      return 403;
    }



    root /usr/share/asuno/www;

    location ~* /css/ {
        expires max;
    }

    location ~* /js/ {
        expires max;
    }
```

I saw this post -
[Nginx: Reject request if header is not present or wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970620/nginx-reject-request-if-header-is-not-present-or-wrong) - but it deals with defined header values. What I need is to check mere existence of the header.

I tried putting `location` directives inside the `if` clause but then nginx throws errors trying to read the config.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you compare it with `false`? `if ($http_StaticCookie = "") { return 403; }`

Answer (score 24):

the comment by Alexey Ten is correct, thanks.

```
if ($http_StaticCookie = "") { return 403; }
```