# NGINX not equal to

Tags: nginx

A client wants me to block access to a page unless the http_user_agent = xxx.

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of an `if else` or `if not` function but this doesn't seem to exist.

If I wanted to block a user agent I could do the below but is there a way to only allow that user agent?

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (xxx) ) {
   return 403; 
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Use the `!~*` operator which is the negated version of `~*`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details.