# How to check if variable is not exist

Tags: nginx

I can't find in docs how I can do negative statement like one below:

```
if !($some_var) {
  ... enter here if $some_var doesn't exist or empty
}
```

I know that I can check that the variable is exits using the if statement:

```
if ($some_var) {
  ...
}
```

But I can't find how to do **if not** statement

Is it possible for NGINX?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NGINX not equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734332/nginx-not-equal-to)

Comment: Use `if ($some_var = '')`

Comment: @emix Thank you for the link, I have already read it, but couldn't understand how to use it in my case (as I not have ~* in if statement).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ($var = false) {
     ....
}
```