# Test if parameter exists and handle proxy_pass in nginx

Tags: nginx, url, parameters

I would like to check if a parameter named "token" exists in the url and is not empty. Based on the result of the test, I would like to `redirect` or use a `proxy_pass`.

Examples:

| url | status |
| --- | --- |
| https://example.com/application/foo?token=123 | proxy_pass |
| [https://example.com/application/foo?token=&bar="abcde"](https://example.com/application/foo?token=&bar=%22abcde%22) | redirect |
| [https://example.com/application/foo?bar="abcde"](https://example.com/application/foo?bar=%22abcde%22) | redirect |
| https://example.com/application/foo?token= &bar="abcde" | redirect |

My current conf:

```
location /application/foo {
    if ($arg_token) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8512/application/foo;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

    return 302 https://example.com/?application=foo&$args;
}
```

But it returns the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block
```

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353572/proxy-pass-cannot-have-uri-part-in-location-given-by-regular-expression/53354944) about the aforementioned error, but it explains the behavior for `location` directives and not for `if`s.

I tried using a [negation of the if test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734332/nginx-not-equal-to) but could not manage to either make the desired behavior or have no error. I also know that `if`s are evil in nginx, but I don't know enough about nginx to do what I want differently.

Comment: Try it the other way around: `if ($args_token = "") { return 302 ...; }`

Comment: It works, thank you. I tried it before in a more convoluted way (I did not know what `$arg_token` could contain so I was trying regex after regex to no avail). You can answer if you want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` within a `location` is best restricted to executing `return` or `rewrite` statements, as [advised here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

In Nginx, an undefined or empty argument both evaluate to the empty string, so you can use `= ""` to invert the logic of your `if` statement. Thus moving the `return` statement inside the block and the `proxy_pass` statement outside of the block.

For example:

```
location /application/foo {
    if ($arg_token = "") {
        return 302 https://example.com/?application=foo&$args;
    }
    proxy_pass ...;
    ...
}
```