# Kubernetes ingress conditional routing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Is it possible to configure an ingress controller in Kubernetes to route the HTTP requests to a service only if the incoming requests have a certain value for a header?

Example

An HTTP request with following header

```
X-MY-CUSTOM-HEADER: accepted-value
```

should be forwarded to service1

An HTTP request with following header

```
X-MY-CUSTOM-HEADER: invalid-value
```

should be blocked

If is possible could you detail a bit or point to some documentation as I wasn't able to find documentation for such usecase

Comment: There's an example in `Istio` docs https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#precedence . It uses `envoy proxy` under the hood, so I believe you can use it directly as ingress controller in cluster, though I've no experience with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an nginx ingress controller you can do it with a [Configuration snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation. Then you can add something like this:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  map $http_x_custom_header $not_ok {
      default "1";
      Value1  "0";
      Value2  "0";
      Value3  "0";
  }

  if ($not_ok) {
      return 403; 
  }
```

Some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972508/2989261).

Comment: The above doesn't work for me. I'm injecting a map directive via the "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet" annotation as suggested above and I'm getting this error message on the nginx ingress pod:

```"map" directive is not allowed here```

Comment: I'm not sure where it's adding it in your nginx config. Maybe you have another map directive?  You can try server-snippet too.  As per the docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map map needs to be added in the http context and configuration-snippet adds the config within the location snippet that is under the http context.

Comment: Just tried "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet", sam error message ""map" directive is not allowed here" :(

Comment: Try adding it in the configmap (http snippet) https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#http-snippet

Comment: Please take a look here if you can. I just created a new question regarding my particular issue, thank you for your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941847/map-directive-not-read-properly-nginx-ingress-controller-kubernetes

Comment: map directive is not allowed inside the configuration-snippet

Answer (score 0):

Traefik 2.0, Istio and Ambassador support Header based routing.

More information from https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/header-based-ingress-routing/6322