# nginx read custom response header

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to log data from custom header. In response:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 09 Nov 2015 16:09:09 GMT
Server:nginx/1.9.4
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Extended-Info:{"c":70}
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.12
```

In php script (Symfony2):

```
$response->headers->set('X-Extended-Info', json_encode($info))
```

I wanna write in log data from "X-Extended-Info".

Nginx config:

```
log_format main_log '$extended_info';
server {
    set $extended_info '-';
    if ($sent_http_x_extended_info != '') {
        set $extended_info $sent_http_x_extended_info;
    }
   ...
}
```

And in log I see only '-'.
I read [nginx - read custom header from upstream server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431496/nginx-read-custom-header-from-upstream-server), but this solution doesn't work in my case (I tried to use $upstream_http_, $http_).

Is possible to read response from phpfpm?
Thank you.

Comment: When I use $sent_http_connection, it works. When I use the most other headers, $sent_http_ is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` directive works before your request send to backend, so at that time there is no `$sent_http_...` variable.

You could use `map` directive.

```
log_format main_log '$extended_info';

map $sent_http_x_extended_info $extended_info {
    default $sent_http_x_extended_info;
    "" "-";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that Niomin had , where the expected header just showed up as "-". I was able to get this working by simply changing my `fastcgi_pass` directive to an `upstream` value, before i was just hardcoding it to a unix socket like the below shows:

`#fastcgi_pass   unix:/home/phillip/php.sock;
 fastcgi_pass php_backend;`

Creating an entry for `upstream` servers i believe is necessary to log the cool `$upstream_http_*` response headers...below is what i created to replace my hardcoded `unix` socket...

`upstream php_backend
{
server unix:/home/phillip/php.sock;
}`

Then i edited the `log_format` to include that `upstream_http_x_forwarded_by`

`log_format  main  '$host - $remote_addr - [$time_local] "$request" ' '$status "X-Powered-By $upstream_http_x_powered_by "$http_referer" ''"$http_user_agent"';`