# Nginx rate limiting based on apiid/apikey

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I am using a rate  liming based on ip address and below example work's perfectly for that.

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

    ...

    server {

        ...

        location /search/ {
            limit_req zone=one burst=5;
        }
```

Now we need to implement rate limiting based  on apiid/apikey which  will part  of http request.Each api key  will have restricted number  of connections and when that goes beyond the restricted number i must give 503 or some thing  like  that.

How to get the apikey/apid from url   into  a variable  and set a limit for each apikey we have ?

Comment: limit_req_zone $http_yourheader zone=one:10m rate=1r/s; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431496/nginx-read-custom-header-from-upstream-server

Comment: Thanks @thesearentthedroids. It worked.