# Nginx $upstream_addr variable doesn't work in if condition

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm running a reverse proxy using `proxy_pass` directive from [ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html). I want to [forbid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223175/nginx-reverse-proxy-deny-access-to-specific-backend-ip-addresses) access to certain backend IP address ranges (like `172.0.0.0/24`). I've tried

```
if ($upstream_addr ~* "^172.*") {                                     
    return 403;                                                    
}
add_header X-mine "$upstream_addr";
```

both in `server` and `location` context but it doesn't work, i.e. Nginx still returns 200:

```
$ curl localhost -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.17.0
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2020 12:58:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Tue, 24 Sep 2019 14:49:10 GMT
ETag: "5d8a2ce6-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-mine: 172.20.0.2:80
```

What am I missing? (Note that I added the content of `$upstream_addr` variable to `X-mine` header for debugging.)

Comment: The `$upstream_addr` variable seems to be empty when the if condition gets evaluated. I think so because `$upstream_addr = ""` is true.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the `if` directive is run before the upstream request is sent, while the `$upstream_addr` header is only set *after* the upstream request has completed. I have tried and failed to find definitive documentation that explains the precise process, but the nginx documentation seems to be missing a number of things that one might wish for.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540402/8672434), and also [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) for a little more guidance. I'm not actually sure quite what you're trying to achieve so I can't offer any hope about whether or not it's possible.