# Nginx reverse proxy - deny access to specific backend IP addresses

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm running Nginx reverse proxy using `proxy_pass` directive from [ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html). Is there a way to forbid access to certain backend IP address ranges? I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208343/nginx-upstream-addr-variable-doesnt-work-in-if-condition) but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi, yes possible and easy to do: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/

Comment: Hi @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX, your link is about denying requests based on client IP addresses. I'm interested in backend (upstream) IP addresses.

Comment: hum... I got the solution on the response of the following question: what the difference between a "client IP" and a "backend IP"? when you got he answer you'll find the solution. Enjoy