# How to read client header?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am following [nginx - read custom header from upstream server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431496/nginx-read-custom-header-from-upstream-server) . My requirement is to read a http header and send it as a cookie to upstream server
So I have following code in location block

```
if ($http_remote_user){

        add_header Set-Cookie  UCM_INFO=$http_remote_user;
}
```

I can see in logs(error.log) that I am getting the value of remote_user but  the above mentioned block is not getting executed.What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer so that it helps others.I was able to figure out the solution.Since I had unserscores in headers so nginx was rejecting the headers.
So we need to put below in conf file

```
underscores_in_headers on
```

Restarted the server and viola it worked.